# site has margin on left and top

Tags: html, css

So i'm making a login page for my website, and for some reason the website just kind of floats to the bottom right, so everytime i enter the website i have to manually scroll so it centers itself. I've tried searching for the problem but i cant seem to find it
[screen of the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIpgD.jpg)

this is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="form-box">
    <div class="button-box">
        <div id="knop"></div>
        <button type="button" class="toggle-btn">log In</button>
        <button type="button" class="toggle-btn">register</button>
      
    </div>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <img src="../site/fotos/duimpje.jpg">
      <img src="../site/fotos/duimpje.jpg">
      <img src="../site/fotos/duimpje.jpg">
    </div>
    <form class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="user id" required>
      <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="enterpassword" required>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>remember password</span>
      <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS

```
    .hero{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../site/fotos/duimpje.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
.form-box{
  width: 380px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 6% auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button-box{
  width: 220px;
  margin: 35px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow:0 0 20px 9px grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.toggle-btn{
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

#knop{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f,#ffad06);
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.social-icons{
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-icons img{
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #7f7f7f3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.input-group {
  top: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-field{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.submit-btn{
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f,#ffad06);
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Set margin and padding of `body` to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, i had a random 5% margin somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the web-browsers add margin to the `<body>` element.

If you don't want that margin, you need to specify the following code in your CSS file:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me, this is for a school project and i have to put all the CSS into one file so that would mess up all other pages.

Comment: Then you can add the css inside the `<body>` tag itself, something like: `<body style="margin: 0">`.

Comment: I found the problem, i had a padding 5% somewhere. Thanks for the help though!